# Python: Can't figure out how to get the right format for to_datetime()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime-format

I'm trying to get data from a CSV to format correctly for dates.  They read as

```
1-Sep-14
```

So in the day-month-year format, but separated by a dash, and not padded with a 0 for the days.  My best guess for how to parse this was

```
pandas.to_datetime("1-Sep-14", "%-d-%b-%y")
```

but that failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `infer_datetime_format`:

```
pd.to_datetime("1-Sep-14",infer_datetime_format=True)# "%d-%m-%y")
```

gives :

```
Timestamp('2014-09-01 00:00:00')
```

If you want to remove hour-minute-second, you can :

```
pd.to_datetime("1-Sep-14",infer_datetime_format=True)# "%d-%m-%y").date()
```

which gives :

```
datetime.date(2014, 9, 1)
```

Comment: Cool, I'll try to leverage this into a solution--but any guess as to why it's not working when I try to just do `pd.read_csv(filepath, parse_dates="date", infer_datetime_format=True)`?

Comment: I've checked that it is working even for missing values(it drops those rows), slightly different format like :`sep-18-2018`. But doesn't work for `sep,18,2018`. So  it may be due to inconsistency in format.